# Sonnar Runner for Android

Tags: android, gradle, sonarqube, sonar-runner

Pmy problem with sonnar-runner is not show coverage report on Sonar. My struct:

```
src/java/

src/androidTest/
```

Sonar is usually showing code metrics, but it not showing the covarege report

Sonar.properties

```
sonar.projectKey=android-sonarqube-runner
sonar.projectName=Project
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.sources=src/com/asdf/android/gva/
sonar.test=src/androidTest/
sonar.language=java
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
"sonar.profile", "My project"
sonar.authenticator.createUsers:true
#sonar.profile=Android Lint
#pdf rules
sonar.pdf.password:admin
sonar.pdf.username:admin
```